# How docker manage volumes when scaling up compose project?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What if have 10 instance of any container which needs presistant storage, so on 10 instance how docker will manage volume for them, i've defined volume in docker-compose.yml

i didn't find anything regarding this that what will happen when multiple instance will run? 
1. will docker create new folders for each instance or 
2. share same folder to all of them (this will lead data corrption)?

here is my sample `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
    consul:
        #image: myappteam/consul:3.4.0
        build: ./consul
        container_name: consul
        hostname: consul
        domainname: consul
        restart: always
        volumes:
           - myapp-data:/data/consul
    consului:
        #image: myappteam/consul-ui:3.4.0
        build: ./consul-ui
        container_name: consul-ui
        hostname: consul-ui
        domainname: consul-ui
        ports:
          - 8500:8500
        restart: always
        volumes:
           - myapp-data:/data/consului
    nginx:
        #image: myappteam/nginx:3.4.0
        build: ./nginx
        container_name: nginx
        hostname: nginx
        domainname: nginx
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        volumes:
           - myapp-logs:/logs/nginx_access_logs
           - myapp-logs:/logs/nginx_error_logs
        restart: always


volumes:
  myapp-data:
  myapp-logs:
  myapp-bundle:
  myapp-source:
```

so in above example, myapp-data is plan i want to have all data so i was thinking when i'll increase instance of nginx, consul, will they use same myapp-data volume or create new volume? because if it will use same instance then data will corrupted because two instance will write same files..

so in that case what should i do?